# Approximate vs. Strict Factor model specification in R

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis, econometrics, finance

Background:
Generally, pooled time-series cross-sectional regressions utilize a strict factor model (i.e. require the covariance of residuals is zero). However, in time series such as security returns where strong comovements exist, the assumption that returns obey a strict factor model is easily rejected.

In an approximate factor model, a moderate level of correlation and autocorrelation among residuals and factors themselves (as opposed to a strict factor model where the correlation of residuals is zero). Approximate factor models allow only correlations that are not marketwide. When we examine different samples at different points in time, approximate factor models admit only local autocorrelation of residuals. This condition guarantees that when the number of factors goes to infinity (i.e., when the number of assets is very large), eigenvalues of the covariance matrix remain bounded. We will assume that autocorrelation functions of residuals decays to zero.

Connor (2007) provides additonal background [here](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1024709).

QUESTION: What function do I use to construct an approximate factor model in R? Perhaps this is a variation of the GLS procedure.